# Game View Displaying different than Scene View?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Scene View: https://i.gyazo.com/421de90843c4f77202f982ea221efecb.mp4

Game View: https://i.gyazo.com/ad3209bc82e0690192f97e24e3fd3eb1.mp4

These are the 2 gifs of what is happening, if you don't want to click them, I can summarize what's happening. In the game view, im teleporting around, and in the scene view, i move around fine. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: For some reason you seem to also make the camera flip around .. you can see the cube jumping from left to right ... that's because you invert the camera size along with the player ... my guess: Your camera is a child of your player object and you forgot that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player isn't teleporting around. It is moving smoothly as you can see in your scene view. You can also confirm this by looking at the x and y co-ordinates of your player object in the Inspector, and I'm sure you'll see that the values aren't jumping around wildly.

What's happening is that your camera is flipping around the axis as your player changes direction, which is making it look like your player is jumping around relative to the black box. If you notice, you can see the camera icon popping in and out in the background of clip of from the scene view you showed. If you check the position of your camera in the inspector, I'm sure you'll see the values jumping as your character changes direction.

Check your code that's controlling your camera and I'm sure you'll find your bug.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had the camera parented, so that must be the problem!